# Could our physical universe be time-irreversible?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

Suppose that in our universe, there were two initial states which lead to the same outcome state after one time step. How could we possibly remember which of the two steps we came from if the arrangement of our brain cells is exactly the same independent of which state was before? Thus, is not the supposition of time reversibility somewhat dubious, because we would never know whether it is true if it is true?

Comment: I think you can get a idea from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem)

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you. I think what you are trying to do is to apply this theorem in order to show that time reversibility is true. But if we can't distinguish between states, how could we possibly check the validity of the conclusion of the Poincaré recurrence theorem?

Comment: Or rather, if we don't even know of the existence of "parallel" states that look the same and that we couldn't distinguish from others.

Comment: The irreversibility of time is simply a consequence of the fact that energy spreads out in space. Why does it do that? Because there is always more "over there" than there is "over here" and a clock, by definition, is a system that has a localized energy reservoir "over here". That is also the reason why there is not just one global time variable: clocks are localized, hence there can be more than one of them.

Comment: Interesting supposition. On the other hand, what is the use of asking a question that *cannot* be answered? If you're serious about your idea reformulate it in the form of an experiment that can prove or disprove it.

Comment: @Themis I think that's impossible. With some effort I can probably prove that it is impossible. So this probably means that my question is answered in a way.

Comment: I don't think though that the question's formulation was entirely clear. Also, perhaps you were already one step further and thought of assigning particular measures to different "branches" and then showing that there are limits to that or something like that?

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous My point is that if reversibility erases memory and memory is required to test reversibility, the question cannot be answered. Perhaps we've had this conversation a hundred times already, but no one can tell. Your question highlights the fact that the observer cannot be separated from the observation, which is a philosophical principle that I agree with.

Answer (score 0):

All matter tends towards entropy.  You could look at the second law of thermodynamics which says that heat will always move from hotter objects to colder objects, to even things out as it were.  Or you could say that you could shuffle a deck of cards billions and billions of times and they would never come back in perfect order.  So in answer to your question, you just need to look at the two potential starting points and the end point.  The starting point that is more orderly than the end point is the likely true direction of time.